# How does one add individual files with DVC?

Tags: git, dvc

Suppose I run the following commands:

```
# set up DVC

mkdir foo
cd foo && git init
dvc init
git add * && git commit -m "dvc init"


# make a data file

mkdir -p bar/biz
touch bar/biz/boz


# add the data file

dvc add bar/biz/boz
```

And DVC outputs the following:

```
To track the changes with git, run:

  git add bar/biz/.gitignore bar/biz/boz.dvc
```

---

This last part is what I would like to avoid.  Preferably, DVC would only change the top level `.gitignore` (located at the project root, where `git init` was executed), and will change only DVC files at the top level.

**And here's why:**

I have a rather large dataset developed in an original work more or less ad-hoc. This data is not systematically organized, nor do I want to organize it as-is.

Instead, I want to incrementally add this old, bespoke data to the DVC directory tree.  And each time I add some of the data to the tree, I want to check it in with DVC as I would if I were modifying code or mixing one project's code into another.

However, DVC wants to create a local file and gitignore at every location I add.  This creates a mess and I have no reasonable faith that it will be easy to maintain all of these atomic and distributed datastores.

---

**The question:**

What is the preferred way to incrementally add data in DVC so that DVC uses the root gitignore and root DVC files/items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming bar/ is the dataset directory you're incrementally adding to, you can instead

```
dvc add bar
```

This creates a bar.dvc file and writes to .gitignore at the top level.

When you update content in bar/, `dvc add` it again or use `dvc commit` to register the new dataset version. The new files get added to the project cache and the .dvc file gets an updated `md5` hash that identifies to the latest directory structure.

Some docs:
https://dvc.org/doc/start/data-management#making-changes
https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/add
https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/project-structure/internal-files#structure-of-the-cache-directory

Comment: Sounds like I'll have to create a .dvc for every file or directory added.